# Menu Opened/Closed States Inherited in Children with Staggered Transitions in Tailwind/React

Tags: css, reactjs, design-patterns, tailwind-css

I'm struggling to figure out how to code a header/menu in my React/Tailwind app.

Here are the requirements:

- Header contains two sub-sections: Primary navigation and secondary navigation.
- On desktop the primary navigation is on the left, and the secondary navigation is on the right.
- On mobile the header contains a hamburger menu that contains both the primary and secondary navigation.
- When this hamburger menu opens each navigation item appears with a staggered transition-delay.

**What is the cleanest/most elegant approach to implement this with Tailwind?**

I thought about separating Header/Navigation/NavigationItem into their own components, but the issue with this is that the Header needs to be aware of the NavigationItem components so that it can pass a isMenuOpen parameter to tell them to animate-in/out when the menu opens/closes.

It looks like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleMenuToggle = (isMenuOpen) => {
    setIsMenuOpen(isMenuOpen)
  }

  return (
    <Header onMenuToggle={handleMenuToggle}>
      <Navigation appearance="primary">
        <NavigationItem appearance="primary" index={0} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
          Menu Item #1
        </NavigationItem>
        <NavigationItem appearance="primary" index={1} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
          Menu Item #2
        </NavigationItem>
        <NavigationItem appearance="primary" index={2} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
          Menu Item #3
        </NavigationItem>
        <NavigationItem appearance="primary" index={3} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
          Menu Item #4
        </NavigationItem>
      </Navigation>
      <Navigation appearance="secondary">
        <NavigationItem appearance="secondary" index={4} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
          Facebook
        </NavigationItem>
        <NavigationItem appearance="secondary" index={5} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
          Twitter
        </NavigationItem>
      </Navigation>
    </Header>
  )
}
```

This isn't elegant and the components are too heavily tied to each other.

Another option was to do it purely in CSS with a class like `.header.is-open .navigation-item {}` but this feels like it goes against the Tailwind patterns.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought about separating Header/Navigation/NavigationItem into their own components, but the issue with this is that the Header needs to be aware of the NavigationItem components so that it can pass a isMenuOpen parameter to tell them to animate-in/out when the menu opens/closes.

I don't see any reason why you can't pass `isMenuOpen` down as a prop.  We can also clean up a lot of the duplication of similar JSX elements.  The only difference from one `NavigationItem` to the next is the `children` content and the `index`, which increases by 1 each time.

We can create a `MenuSection` component that loops through items and applies the same props to all, incrementing the index.

```
const MenuSection = ({ appearance, isMenuOpen, startIndex = 0, menuItems }) => {
    return (
        <Navigation appearance={appearance}>
            {menuItems.map((node, i) => (
                <NavigationItem
                    key={i}
                    appearance={appearance}
                    index={i + startIndex}
                    isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
                >
                    {node}
                </NavigationItem>
            ))}
        </Navigation>
    );
};
```

This `menuItems` prop is an `array` of anything which can be used as the `children` property of the `NavigationItem`.  So the elements can be a `string` or an element.

If we try to use this in `App` then it gets weird because we have to set the `startIndex` on the second `MenuSection` based on the count of items in the first.  Does the index for the secondary navigation really need to continue from where the primary left off?  If it does then we should extract one level deeper so that we can look at the `length` property of the first list.

```
const MenuPair = ({ isMenuOpen, primaryItems, secondaryItems }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <MenuSection
        isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
        appearance="primary"
        startIndex={0}
        menuItems={primaryItems}
      />
      <MenuSection
        isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
        appearance="secondary"
        startIndex={primaryItems.length}
        menuItems={secondaryItems}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleMenuToggle = (isMenuOpen) => {
    setIsMenuOpen(isMenuOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Header onMenuToggle={handleMenuToggle}>
      <MenuPair
        isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
        primaryItems={[
          "Menu Item #1",
          "Menu Item #2",
          "Menu Item #3",
          "Menu Item #4"
        ]}
        secondaryItems={["Facebook", "Twitter"]}
      />
    </Header>
  );
};
```

For this 6-item menu we haven't shortened the code by abstracting pieces into their own components, but at least we've ensured that the `index` property will always index properly without having to hard-code the numbers.